# How could I get the result for "For" operation?

Tags: java, xpath, return

What I wanted to do is get the resut which is generated from the following class:

```
public class QueryXML {

public String query;
public QueryXML(String query){
    this.query=query;   
}

public void query() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,IOException,XPathExpressionException {


  // Standard of reading an XML file
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder;
Document doc = null;
XPathExpression expr = null;

builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.parse("C:data.xml");

// create an XPathFactory
XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

// create an XPath object
XPath xpath = xFactory.newXPath();

// Compile the XPath expression
expr = xpath.compile(query);
// Run the query and get a nodeset
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

// Cast the result to a DOM NodeList
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result; 
for (int i=0; i<nodes.getLength();i++){
 System.out.print(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
  }
 }
}
```

This class is called from this other one:

```
public class FindUser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        String Queries[]={"//Employees/Employee/Firstname/City/@value", "//Employees/Employee/Firstname/Lastname/@value"};

        for (int x =0; x < Queries.length; x++){
            String query = Queries[x];
        QueryXML process = new QueryXML(query);
        process.query();

      }
  }
}
```

Those class are working fine and I can see the result in console, but I would like to assign the rsult of "process.query()" to one variable in order to work with it after this proccess.

I dont know if it's possible or even if it's a good idea to assign the "for" operation to a variable and give it back as a return(something).

Many thanks

Cheers!!

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to return your results from the `query()` method:

```
public NodeList query() throws ParserConfigurationException, 
                        SAXException,IOException,XPathExpressionException {

        ...

        // Cast the result to a DOM NodeList
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        return nodes;
}
```

You can then add the results to an array for processing later:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, 
                        ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        String Queries[]={
                "//Employees/Employee/Firstname/City/@value",
                "//Employees/Employee/Firstname/Lastname/@value"
        };

        List<NodeList> results = new ArrayList<NodeList>();
        for (int x =0; x < Queries.length; x++){
                String query = Queries[x];
                QueryXML process = new QueryXML(query);
                results.add(process.query());
        }
  }
```

Comment: Hi it seems works when I have just one query however when I try to do it with more than one, I'm receiving the next error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Ok, fixed. I've improved the amount of memory and now is working. Perhaps the is any other way to fix it like clean the memry before to work with the second query or something like that, but I dont know it. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you process each result when found rather than adding all the results to a list then your program will consume less memory. Alternatively, you could serialise the results and store them on disk. Your results list could just store file references that way.

Answer (score 1):

> Those class are working fine and I can see the result in console, but I would like to assign the rsult of "process.query()" to one variable in order to work with it after this proccess.

So you have to change the type of the return value of your function vom "void" to f.e. "org.w3c.dom.Document" an you have to change your function so that it returns a valid xml document

Answer (score 0):

Replace your  `System.out.print(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());` with  `System.out.print(nodes.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());` In mean time you also need to check for the null for `getFirstChild` when your tag is  somthing like this `<a/>`